# i have an error in my rootView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     et=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.et1);

    String str=et.getText().toString();



    Fragment frag=new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle1=new Bundle();
    bundle1.putString("name", str);
    frag.setArguments(bundle1);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_body, frag).commit();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentmovie, container, false);
}
```

}

it is displaying rootView cannot be resolved,i need to add edit text et to string str so that using bundle i can pass it to the next fragment

Comment: Do it as `View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentmovie, container, false);` and also return `rootView` from `onCreateView`

Comment: rootView should be the one which you are inflating and returning in the last line

Comment: do i need to replace  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentmovie, container, false); with return rootview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Add inflater then return.

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentmovie, container, false);
 et=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.et1);

String str=et.getText().toString();



Fragment frag=new Fragment();
Bundle bundle1=new Bundle();
bundle1.putString("name", str);
frag.setArguments(bundle1);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_body, frag).commit();

return rootView ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate it first:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentmovie, container, false);
...
return rootview;
```

Comment: return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentmovie, container, false); with return rootview